# create a new record in service entity

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2016

I have seen example of creating Accounts Entity records, Contacts entity records through C#, i wanted to know how do we create a service record in CRM through C#(.net) code.

Eg: We already have "Plumbing service" record in **service** entity view. So i wanted to create a new record in service entity through C# code (early or late binding doesn't matter).

Can someone help me on this with code.

Comment: Did you already try to simply adopting the examples for Accounts and Contacts? Did you encounter any problems? You should try before asking for code here.

Comment: Yes i had tried and tested

Answer (score 4):

Quite some XML is required when creating this Services from code. Additionally, before you can create a Service you will need to create a ResourceSpec and a ConstraintBasedGroup.

First create a ConstraintBasedGroup:

```
var bu = context.BusinessUnitSet.First().ToEntityReference();

var cbg = new ConstraintBasedGroup
{
    BusinessUnitId = bu,
    Name = "CBG1",
    Constraints = "<Constraints><Constraint><Expression><Body>false</Body><Parameters><Parameter name=\"resource\"/></Parameters></Expression></Constraint></Constraints>"
};
var cbgId = OrganizationService.Create(cbg);
```

Then create a ResourceSpec:

```
var resSpec = new ResourceSpec
{
    BusinessUnitId = bu,
    Name = "RS1",
    RequiredCount = 1,
    ObjectiveExpression = "<Expression><Body>udf\"Random\"(factory,resource,appointment,request,leftoffset,rightoffset)</Body><Parameters><Parameter name=\"factory\"/><Parameter name=\"resource\"/><Parameter name=\"appointment\"/><Parameter name=\"request\"/><Parameter name=\"leftoffset\"/><Parameter name=\"rightoffset\"/></Parameters><Properties EvaluationInterval=\"P0D\" evaluationcost=\"0\"/></Expression>",
    GroupObjectId = cbgId
};
var resSpecId = OrganizationService.Create(resSpec);
```

And finally, you can create your Service:

```
var svc = new Service
{
    Name = "Service1",
    Granularity = "FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=15",
    ResourceSpecId = new EntityReference(ResourceSpec.EntityLogicalName, resSpecId),
    InitialStatusCode = new OptionSetValue(0),
    Duration = 15
};
OrganizationService.Create(svc);
```

I would suggest you create similar things using the UI of CRM in case you are wondering about the specific formats of the XML you require. The XML I used in my examples is pretty much the default XML CRM generates.

Comment: You'll find some additional contact in the SDK: SampleCode\CS\BusinessDataModel\ScheduleAndAppointment\ScheduleResource.cs. But that is about it, there isn't much documentation on this topic. @Henrik has probably provided the best documentation you'll find with this answer!

Comment: Works like a charm. @Henrik : Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Henrik. :)